# How to get key list from razor engine template in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am working with .net core.
Project contains many dynamic razor engine templates. All the templates are generated by
the third-party users. So the system can not use any common model or can not generate
the individual model for fill razor engine template with values.
I need to get list of all the keys which are using in razor engine template.

```
<acord>
  <student>
     <firstName>@Model.StudentFirstName</firstName>
     <lastName>@Model.StudentLastName</lastName>
     @if(@Model.StudentPhone != null)
     {
        <phone>@Model.StudentPhone</phone>
     }
  </student>
  <parents>
     <firstName>@Model.parentFirstName</firstName>
     <lastName>@Model.parentLastName</lastName>
  </parents>
</acord>
```

As per above sample, I need list of keys like,
@Model.StudentFirstName, @Model.StudentLastName, @Model.StudentPhone, @Model.parentFirstName
@Model.parentLastName

I have spent couple of days for find the solution on internet, but didn't get any proper solution. So how can I get list of keys from razor engine template?

Comment: I am not clear about what your meaning. Could  you explain more? Do you use Asp.net Core Web App temple in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, it's using Visual Studio. Razor engine template is using for prepare API request. System user's will create API request on their side. So system will not able to use any particular model and specific individual models for each API request. That's why I need a list of each model keys from the razor engine template.

Comment: Do you mean you want to call an ASP.NET API in an ASP.NET Razor web application, and show the data in the cshtml?

Comment: No, it will not display anything on cshtml. razor engine template is using for prepare API request from the asp.net core system. Any type of API will be accessible from the Asp.net core project. system users will save all the details of API and api request in razor engine template format. Now when API will fire then it will pick the razor engine template and then replace the values and will prepare the request for an API call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular expressions. Based on the example you posted, the following works:

```
var input = @"<acord>
  <student>
     <firstName>@Model.StudentFirstName</firstName>
     <lastName>@Model.StudentLastName</lastName>
     @if(@Model.StudentPhone != null)
     {
        <phone>@Model.StudentPhone</phone>
     }
  </student>
  <parents>
     <firstName>@Model.parentFirstName</firstName>
     <lastName>@Model.parentLastName</lastName>
  </parents>
</acord>";
var pattern = @"@Model.([\w.\[\]]*)";
var keys = Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups.Cast<Group>().LastOrDefault())
        .Select(g => g.Value)
        .Distinct()        
        .ToList();
foreach(var k in keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(k);
}
```

Output:

```
StudentFirstName
StudentLastName
StudentPhone
parentFirstName
parentLastName
```

Comment: Yes that is great.  Can above mentioned pattern identify keys like "@Model.parentPhone[0].mobile", "@Model.parentPhone[1].mobile" ? Keys with square brackets and number inside brackets.

Comment: With a little modification it can. Updated the answer.